# scroll view content offset non responsive in viewDidLoad

Tags: swift

scrollView.contentOffset does work properly inside button func but the same code is non responsive in the viewDidLoad func

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBAction func scrollBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    scrollView.contentOffset.x = 200
   }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.contentOffset.x = 200


    }
```

i am trying to change the initial position of  the scroll view

Answer (score 0):

Try using it in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear. May be the reason behind it is not working in viewDidLoad  is that the view has not get rendered at the time the viewDidLoad invoked.